# JavaFX: set ClickListener on nodes of a LineChart

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, linechart

I have a JavaFX Application which calculates some data first and afterwards add the datapoints on the LineChart. I would like to add a ClickListener on the nodes, that if the user clicks on any node on the graph, the corresponding value will appear in a TableView or something else. But I can't retrieve the values of the nodes.

The code is as followed:

```
lineChart.getData().add(series);
series.getNode().setOnMouseClicked(nodeClicked);
```

Code for the EventListener:

```
EventHandler<MouseEvent> nodeClicked = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.println("clicked");
        }
};
```

I also tried to set the Listener on the LineChart but I can't find in the event-object the corresponding node information like value etc.

Thank you in advance, best regards

Comment: That should add a listener to the node for the *series* (i.e. the line that makes up the line chart). Is that what you want, or did you want a listener on the nodes for the individual data points?

Comment: @James_D Exactly, I'd like a listener on every datapoint, so if you click on a point on the graph, you should get the values of that datapoint.

Comment: So you need to get each node from the actual `XYChart.Data` objects, and add listeners to those.

Comment: @James_D But how? Firstly, I create a XYChart.Data Object with the 2 values for x and y. Afterwards I add them to the series and finally add the series to the LineChart. If I try to set the Listener after declaring the Data Object directly, I get a NullPointerException.

Comment: Well, no-one can tell you what's wrong with code they can't see. My best guess is that you're retrieving the node from the data before the data are added to the chart (the node isn't created until the data are added to the chart). But presumably you can figure out from the stack trace what is actually null...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are adding the handler to the node associated with the data *series*. This node in a line chart is the line itself, so you should see your console output when you click on the line.

To have the listener respond to clicks on the data points themselves, you need to add the listeners to the node associated with the individual `XYChart.Data` instances.

Note that these nodes are only created after the data are added to the series *and* the series is added to the chart; so you must be careful to only add the event handler after these have occurred.

Here is a SSCCE:

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LineChartWithEventHandlers extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());
        Series<Number, Number> series = new Series<>();
        series.setName("Data");

        chart.getData().add(series);

        // handler for clicking on line:
        series.getNode().setOnMouseClicked(e -> System.out.println("Click on series"));

        Random rng = new Random();
        for (int x = 0 ; x <= 20 ; x++) {
            Data<Number, Number> data = new Data<>(x, rng.nextInt(100));
            series.getData().add(data);

            // handler for clicking on data point:
            data.getNode().setOnMouseClicked(e -> 
                System.out.printf("Click on data [%d, %d]%n", data.getXValue(), data.getYValue()));
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(chart);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Screen shot after clicking on the line, two different data points, and the line again:

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much. You were right, I added the Listener before I added the series to the chart.

Comment: @serij Yes: see the third paragraph of the answer.

Comment: In essence, for every chart symbol it creates a separate handler which contains a reference of the corresponding `Data` item. This works fine when the points are not so many. But when a chart contains a few series with thousands of points in each it may become too unwieldy. I tried to obtain the reference of the data item from the mouse event target (that is `StackPane`) in a single common handler shared among all the nodes, but have not succeded. Is there any way to access the data via its respective node?